# Como montar um link na JSP com o value de um input?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Tem como montar um link(href) ou um action(form) pegando o valor de um input para passar para um @PathVariable de um método no controller?

Meu código é seguinte no controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="atendimentos/{numeroChamado}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView detalhe(@PathVariable("numeroChamado") Long numeroChamado){
    ...
}
```

Gostaria de montar o link em um href ou form, por exemplo

```
<form:form action="/atendimentos/{valorDoInput}" id="formBusca" method="get" >
          <input type="text" id="buscaChamado" placeholder="Número do Chamado" name="numeroChamado" />
        </form:form>
```

ou

```
<a href="/atendimentos/{valorDoInput}"><input type="text" id="buscaChamado" placeholder="Número do Chamado" name="numeroChamado" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer com javascript, de forma simples. Para isto basta ter um evento no seu *input text* e sempre que o valor dele for alterado iremos alterar o atributo `action` do *form*.

Partindo de algo parecido com o seu formulário:

```xml
<form:form action="" id="formBusca" method="get" >
    <input type="text" id="numeroChamado" placeholder="Número do Chamado" />
</form:form>
```

Podemos fazer algo assim em javascript puro:

```js
numeroChamado.onchange = function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('formBusca');
  form.action = '/atendimentos/' + this.value;
};
```

Veja aqui um exemplo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMEZYO

Caso use jQuery, pode simplificar para algo como isto:

```js
$('#numeroChamado').change(function() {
  $('#formBusca').attr('action', '/atendimentos/' + this.value);
});
```

Veja aqui um exemplo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKqRza

Em ambos exemplos executamos uma função no evento `onchange` do *input text* `numeroChamado`, alterando o `action` do *form* `formBusca`.